# How to alter a presentation to display all texts in upper case?

Tags: python-pptx

I haven't found in the [documentation](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) how to display a paragraph in upper case (all capitals). I don't want to change the underlying text, only how it's displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not implemented in pxthon-pptx. Nonetheless, you could do it via

```
paragraph.font._element.attrib['cap'] = "all"
```